# AWS Amplify deployment: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm deploying my first project to AWS Amplify, it's just a basic React app with some divs and text to test out the deployment.

It builds and runs in VS code and is bound to Git.
I ran thorough the Amplify Console wizard, setting up the build to use Webpack which completed successfully and deployed uploading:

- index.html
- index.css
- main.js
- and a couple of images

However when I visit the link I get:

> This site can’t be reached
>   `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

How can I investigate what exactly has been deployed to give me clues to why it won't work?

Answer (score 0):

I has assumed that it was the hosting that was the problem but after testing it with Firefox and IE I got more security related messages.
Finally I got it working on my phone on 4G (bypassing the home router) and this worked.